# Caching into subcomponents

Tags: next.js

I'm building a site in nextjs but I came across a problem.
I have the cover of the site, where there is a list of products, and on the top menu the list of product categories.
The products are looking via getStaticProps (So that it is done by the servideor and is cached).
However, the categories are inside a separate component, where inside I need to load the category listing from my API.

getStaticProps does not work in this case as it is not a page but a component.

Fetching inside a useEffect is bad, as each access loads the api.

So the question remains, how can I do this server-side fetch and deliver the cached (json) return? (Simulating getStaticProps)

Comment: You can still use `getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps` at the page level to retrieve the data, and use React context to share this data to the components that needed it.

Comment: Is the category component not composed inside the products page?

Comment: @SamuelGoldenbaum The menu component is loaded on every page, and it's in the menu where I load the categories

Answer (score 0):

As your component is listed on every page, you could consider either using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or local caching in the browser within the shared Category component.

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without
> having to pass props down manually at every level.

But there are [performance considerations](https://blog.logrocket.com/pitfalls-of-overusing-react-context/) using Context and may be overkill here. If you really don't want to hit the API, data is not changing often, and you don't need to pass functions through the component tree, then you could consider some basic browser caching using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const mockAPI = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve([
        {
          id: '1',
          name: 'One'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'Two'
        }
      ]);
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const Component = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (categories === null) {
        let data = window.localStorage.getItem('categories');
        if (data === null) {
          console.info('calling api...');
          data = await mockAPI();
          window.localStorage.setItem('categories', JSON.stringify(data));
        }

        setCategories(JSON.parse(data));
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return <nav>{categories && categories.map((category) => <li key={category.id}>{category.name}</li>)}</nav>;
};

export default Component;
```

The caveat here is you need to know where to clear localStorage. There are many ways to implement this from using basic [timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to looking at [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/)

You could also consider [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) but is probably overkill for something elementary like this.